# Managing Azure Face API images

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm playing with the Azure Face API and enjoying it very much.

I was wondering - where do the images I upload via the API (for example - in order to create a Person Group) stored? Can I view them or download them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Image data is stored by the Azure by referencing them with a persistedId.
According to the discussion, there is no way to view or download the image:

https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/356325-apis/suggestions/14708886-possibility-to-retrieve-the-image-for-a-faceid

Comment: You need to include the relevant information in your answer, not just links

Comment: @Michael, I have added the answer to your question. The link is just for the reference. Can you explain what more are you looking for in the answer?

Comment: The images aren't stored, just the data points for them. Data points are only persisted for the person group feature, just a standard Detect only keeps the data points for 24hr @garvitagrawal answer was accurate